# Expected time to complete dd operation for restoring RetroPie image to microSD?

Tags: macos

I copied the [RetroPie](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup) image (2.6 GB) to a microSD card by running the following command in `bash`:

`sudo dd bs=1m if=retropie-v3.6-rpi2_rpi3.img of=/dev/disk4`

with the result

`2600000000 bytes transferred in 2090.362756 secs (1243803 bytes/sec)`

So it took 2090 seconds (~35 minutes).

I have two questions:

1. Is that a reasonable amount of time to perform that operation based on the technical info below? The card is advertised to have "up to 40 MB/s write" but the operation was only taking place at ~1.2 MB/s.
2. Is there a more efficient way to `dd` the image to my card so that the transfer speed is much higher?

---

### Technical info

**Computer**
MacBook Pro (Mid 2014), OS X 10.11.4
2.5 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

**microSD card**
[SanDisk Extreme 16GB microSDHC UHS-1 Card with Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013CP5F90)

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable anyway. The "Class" of the card requires the card to have a minimum (constant, AFAIK) write speed. For example, Class 10 / U1 requires it to be 10MB/s. Even a Class 2 cards requires 2MB/s.

Comment: @TomYan In reference to comment before edit: using built-in SD slot with supplied adapter

Comment: bs=1m makes it use 1MB blocks.  Smaller blocks will be slower. I don't know the optimal value but I tend to use bs=32m

Answer (score 1):

This guy wrote a script which detemines the best block size for him. Bigger does not mean always better. Maybe you can adapt the script to your needs: http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/

Additionally I use `ctr + t` to see where the copy process is currently.

And you can parallelize the copying process but I have never tested this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160469/how-to-parallelize-dd